# Is it possible to determine the ownership of a PST from a PST?

Tags: outlook, mapi, pst

I believe the answer is no, but need confirmation.
In the binary format of a PST is there some property which can help determine the ownership of the PST correctly ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/332059/dmitry-streblechenko would you happen to know ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ownership in what sense? Unlike POP3/SMTP, IMAP4/SMTP, Exchange, etc., accounts, a PST file does not have an intrinsic user identity, even though one or more email accounts can deliver messages there. Is that what you are after? In that case you need to start with a POP3/SMTP account and see where it delivers the messages to.

Comment: Ownership as in who does it belong to. If user A has created a pst for himself and his outlook account is configured to send all email to the pst then is there some property that can tell me that this PST belongs to user A ?

Comment: No, there is no such information inside the PST file. OST files on the other hand have a special property that ties them uniquely to a particular profile.

Comment: Thanks, can you kindly give me a reference to that property.

Comment: It is only set on OST files and can be accessed only if you parse the OST file, it is not available; programmatically. It is really a blob that has to match the blob in the profile section. It is not available on PST files.

Answer (score 0):

The PR_MDB_PROVIDER (DASL name is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x34140102`) property contains a provider-defined [MAPIUID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc839587.aspx) structure that indicates the type of the message store. Try using any low-level property viewer such as MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy for exploring its values.

Comment: Type of the message store? The OP asks about a PST store. For a PST store, PR_MDB_PROVIDER is always MSPST_UID_PROVIDER (4E495441F9BFB80100AA0037D96E0000).